# Why can't I get rid of the "Cookie Preferences" box in IBM Watson when I am on Watson Knowledge Catalog pages?

Tags: cookies, watson-studio, watson-knowledge-catalog

The Cookies Preferences box that always appears in the bottom right hand corner of the dataplatform.ibm.com web pages when you are in Watson Studio is blocking valuable and necessary action buttons and it is quite a nuisance. Do you all have any idea on how you can permanently get rid of that once and for all? Even if you click on it and you specify your cookie preferences and then accept and save, it comes back on yet another page in the product at some point. This has caused me a lot of pain trying to do screen shots for product tours and labs and clients have commented on this is annoying and intrusive when doing the DTE Watson Knowledge Catalog hands on lab as well.

Answer (score 0):

It should disappear after you saved the preference but it sounds like that is not happening.  Let me get back to you on why that is the case.